# JDBC Sink - Value schema must be of type Struct

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am trying to sink data from Kafka to Postgres and the following is what I have configured -

My zookeeper, Kafka, Schema registry & Kafka Connect is working fine
Even i have configured a Mongo Sink Connector which works fine.

The issue is only with Postgres connector

Kafka topic name - `data-test-topic`
Following is the data on this topic -

```
Key: "A"
{
    "name": "abhishek",
    "lastname": "Rathore"
}
```

Pictorial representation -
[image]
Following is the config i am using for JDBC Sink connector -

```
{
    "name": "postgres-jdbc-sink-connector",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
        "tasks.max": 1,
        "topics": "data-test-topic",
        "connection.url": "jdbc:postgresql://postgresdb:5432/garuna-rgs",
        "connection.user": "postgres",
        "connection.password": "arathore",
        "auto.create": true,
        "auto.evolve": true,
        "insert.mode": "upsert",
        "table.name.format": "init",
        "pk.mode": "record_key",
        "pk.fields": "name",
        "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
        "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
        "value.converter.schemas.enable": false,
        "key.converter.schemas.enable": false
    }
}
```

Postgres table init struct -

```
  Column  | Type | Collation | Nullable | Default | Storage  | Compression | Stats target | Description 
----------+------+-----------+----------+---------+----------+-------------+--------------+-------------
 name     | text |           | not null |         | extended |             |              | 
 lastname | text |           | not null |         | extended |             |              | 
 key      | text |           | not null |         | extended |             |              | 
Access method: heap
```

The Error which JDBC sink connector produces -

```
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Exiting WorkerSinkTask due to unrecoverable exception.
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:618)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:336)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:237)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:206)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:202)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:257)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.Plugins.lambda$withClassLoader$1(Plugins.java:181)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Value schema must be of type Struct
    at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.metadata.FieldsMetadata.extract(FieldsMetadata.java:86)
    at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.metadata.FieldsMetadata.extract(FieldsMetadata.java:67)
    at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.BufferedRecords.add(BufferedRecords.java:115)
    at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.JdbcDbWriter.write(JdbcDbWriter.java:74)
    at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.JdbcSinkTask.put(JdbcSinkTask.java:90)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:587)
    ... 11 more
```

I am not able to solve this problem even after trying different config values for sink connectors, please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So found the following solution as suggested by @onecricketeer

topic data -

```js
{
        schema: {
            type: 'struct',
            fields: [
                {
                    field: 'name',
                    type: 'string',
                    optional: false,
                },
                {
                    field: 'lastname',
                    type: 'string',
                    optional: false,
                },
            ],
        },
        payload: {
            name: 'abhishek',
            lastname: 'rathore',
        },
    }
```

Sink connector config -

```json
{
    "name": "postgres-jdbc-sink-connector",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
        "tasks.max": 1,
        "topics": "data-test-topic",
        "connection.url": "jdbc:postgresql://postgresdb:5432/garuna-rgs",
        "connection.user": "postgres",
        "connection.password": "arathore",
        "auto.create": true,
        "auto.evolve": true,
        "insert.mode": "upsert",
        "table.name.format": "init",
        "pk.mode": "record_value",
        "pk.fields": "name",
        "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
        "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
        "value.converter.schemas.enable": true,
        "key.converter.schemas.enable": false
    }
}
```

Now the data is syncing properly with Postgres

Answer (score 1):

As the error says, the connector requires a Struct.

StringConverter returns a plain String, not a Struct, and therefore the data cannot be parsed to know what fields in your data match the database columns and types.

Refer [Confluent blog](https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-deep-dive-converters-serialization-explained/) on what Converter you should be using.

In particular, `org.apache.kafka.connect.json.StringConverter` is an invalid class name, and `schemas.enable` does nothing for StringConverter, only JSONConverter, so you need

```
"value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
"value.converter.schemas.enable": true,
```

But this also requires you to change your data to actually have a schema.

Comment: Hi @OneCricketeer , yes you are right the class was wrong, made a mistake while writing the question here, based on the table struct can you suggest what else should i add in config file?

Comment: As answered, you'll have to use the correct JSONConverter package and add schema to your data, not produce plain json into the topic

Comment: is there a way i can use Avro converter for this type of data, i have already configured `confluentinc/cp-schema-registry`

Comment: Yes, Avro data will always be structured. You'll need to modify your producer, though, since AvroConverter cannot consume json data